# Equivalent to setOnItemLongClickListener in Ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I created a function in which when the user a simple click on the item, shows a Toast, an alert, on the screen with the item clicked:

Function in my .ts file:

```
itemSelected(item: string) {
    this.toastCtrl.showToast("Selected Item: " + item, 'bottom');
}
```

Button:

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of people" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
  {{ item.firstname }}
</button>
```

This works normally, however now I would like to create a list of options when the user makes a long click on the item. In native Android it is possible to do this using the `setOnItemLongClickListener` method, however I do not know what would be the equivalent in Ionic? Which method equivalent to `setOnItemLongClickListener` in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try out the `press` event provided by Ionic 2 gestures. Check out the docs on gestures [here.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures)

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of people" (press)="itemSelected(item)">
  {{ item.firstname }}
</button>
```

Comment: @cricket_007 His question: "Which method equivalent to setOnItemLongClickListener in Ionic 2?" . The asnwer: ``press`` event. The link is not the answer here. Its for reference if he wants to check it out.

Comment: And I'm simply saying you can show an example usage within your answer, that is all